# MySql - select a record from 18446744073709551615 records

Tags: mysql

my question is simple: let's say that I have hypothetically 18446744073709551615 records in one table (the max number) but I want to select from those records only one something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE ID = 5
```

1.- will the result be so slow to appear?

or if I have another table with only five records and I do the same query

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE2 WHERE ID = 5
```

2.- will the result appear at the same speed as in the first select or will be much faster in this other one?

thanks.

Comment: Seems easy to test ... Have you tried?

Comment: @David: yeah, just load up 2**64 values on your hard drive? By the by, we use a 64 bit identifier for all objects at Facebook. It's a big scale.

Comment: @JeffFerland  I see. I didn't appreciate the scale. But wouldn't the answer be clear from a table that is sufficiently large but still manageable database (e.g. 2^32 records)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's assume for simplicity that the ID column is a fixed-width primary key. It will be found in roughly 64 index lookups ([Wolfram Alpha on that](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log2%2818446744073709551615%29)). Since MySQL / InnoDB uses BTrees, it will be somewhat less than that for disk seeks.

Searching among 1 in a million would take you roughly index lookups. Seeking among 5 values will take [3 index lookups](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log2%285%29) and the whole page will probably fit into one block.

Most of the speed difference will come from data that is being read from disk. The index branching should be a relatively fast operation and functionally you would not notice the difference once the values were cached in RAM. That is to say the first time you select from you 2<sup>64</sup> rows, it will be a little bit to read from a spinning disk, but essentially the same speed for the 5 and 2<sup>64</sup> rows if you were to repeat the query (even ignoring query cache).

Answer (score 3):

No the first one will almost certainly be slower than the second but probably not *that* much slower, provided you have an index on the ID column.

With an index, you can efficiently find the first record meeting the condition and then all the other records will be close by (in the index structures anyway, not necessarily the data area).

I'd say you're more likely to run out of disk storage with the first one before you run out of database processing power :-)